# CSS: Changing width/height after rotation in one direction only

Tags: css, math, geometry, linear-algebra, trigonometry

My end goal is a draggable, resizable, Scalable, and rotatable element, just like the example on: https://daybrush.com/moveable/ only by using css width,height, and transform: rotate, translate.

Say I have a div with following css:

```css
.rect {
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  top:100px;
  left:100px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  
}
```

```html
<div class="rect"></div>
```

If I want to resize the div horizontally to the left, I  just change the width by x pixels. If I want to change it to the right I just change the width by x pixels, and translate(-xpx, 0).

But what if I change the angle? From trying a lot of stuff, I found some of the x and y values for translate to the respective angle, however I feel like there is a more straight forward way than just guessing. E.g: For 90deg, if I want to resize to the left by x px I do translate(-x*0.5px, x*0.5px).

More: what if I want to change both the width & height at the same time?

P.S.: I would rather avoid using libraries, transform: scale or svg

P.P.S:Example to further demonstrate the problem, just changing the width:

```css
.rect {
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  top:100px;
  left:100px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  animation: expand 5s infinite
}

@keyframes expand {
  from {width: 200px;}
  to {width: 2000px;}
}
```

```html
<div class="rect"></div>
```

Fixed, stretching the left side of the original rectagle (now up since rotated 90deg):

```css
.rect {
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  top:100px;
  left:100px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  animation: expand 3s infinite
}

@keyframes expand {
  from {
    width: 200px;
    }
  to {
    width: 800px;
    transform: rotate(90deg) translate(-300px, 300px);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="rect"></div>
```

Comment: Check if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67780518/12750353) helps. There I am computing the transformation matrices for the transformations individually and also combining different transformations in one.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply several transformations to the same object and they will be composed in the order that you specify. Move then rotate, is different than rotate then move.

```css
.rect {
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  top:100px;
  left:100px;
  position: absolute;
}
.t1 {
  background-color: #40d04080;
  /* green shaded rectangle: rotate after translation */
  transform: translate(2cm, 0) rotate(30deg);
}

.t2 {
  background-color: #f0404080;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}

.t3 {
  background-color: #4040f080;
  /* blue shaded rectangle: translate after rotation */
  transform: rotate(30deg) translate(2cm, 0) ;
}
```

```html
<div class="rect t1"></div>
<div class="rect t2"></div>
<div class="rect t3"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I don't see how this is relevant to my problem. Furthermore, the order in which the functions are applied are [right to left](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#values)
The problem described is about the element "moving" from the original position when changing the size, needing a translate to offset that movement. The problem is finding that offset.

Comment: My understanding
Suppose a transforma A and a transforma B, specified as `A B` in the CSS, they will be multiplied in order from left to right. i.e. you have an object X, you apply A, then you get `A X`, then to this transformed result you apply the transformation B, then you will have `B (A X)`, that is equivalent `(B A) X`, the resulting transformation `(B A)`. Do you agree with this?

Comment: For the second problem you may want to set [transform-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) explicitly.